# Check I duplicated alert and remove, Python

Tags: python, file, text, compare

I'm trying my best to solve the following scenario:

I would like to compare 2 files (file1.txt and file2.txt) with each other. The first file(file1.txt) contains dictionaries (strings). They are used to search trough the second file(file2.txt). If an identical string is found in file2.txt it should be removed there. This should go through all strings in file1.

I'm using the following code:

```
import csv
import os

    enter code here

crimefile = open('file1.txt', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(crimefile)
allRows = [row for row in reader]

crimefileB = open('file2.txt', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(crimefileB)
allRowsB = [row for row in reader]

for counter in xrange(0,allRowsB.count()):
    print count
    if allRows[count] == allRowsB[count]: allRowsB[count-2].remove
    enter code here
```

In the attached code I export them to a list, but I don't want to preform the task in this method.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your questino. If you want a list that contains all items of `allRows` that are not present in `allRowsB`, you can use `result = list(set(allRows) - set(allRowsB))`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
import csv
import os

crimefile = open('file1.txt', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(crimefile)

# Sets are much faster for membership checks.  Also, using a generator 
# (the ()'s) instead of a list will save memory, as the entire file will
# not need to loaded in all at once.
filtervals = set((row for row in reader))

out = []
crimefileB = open('file2.txt', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(crimefileB)
for line in reader:
    if line not in filtervals:
        out.append(line)
# Don't forget to close the files you open!
```

`out` will contain file2.txt filtered by file1.txt.

You can also do the last bit as a list comprehension.

```
out = [ line for line in reader if line not in filtervals ]
```